# How to create and split a tar archive and send the results to my server?

Tags: linux, ssh, tar

I would like to create a `.tar` backup of some files on my laptop and send them to my server. My laptop's HDD is not large enough to hold both the original and backup copy of the file. I would like to break the tar archive into 10GB pieces.

Here's what I have so far:

```
tar cvf - /backupdir/ | ssh user@host "split -b 10G -d backup.tar."
```

And the result is

```
split: cannot open 'backup.tar.' for reading: No such file or directory
```

Of course, I could just `tar | ssh "cat > backup.tar"` and then open an SSH shell and split the file then, but I want to be fancy and do this all in one fell swoop.

Comment: you've got an extra `.` after your `backup.tar`

Comment: @Thom Wiggers: The split manpage says split takes the following form:
split [OPTION] [INPUT [PREFIX]]
there's an extra period because I would like my files to be named backup.tar.00 and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell split to read from STDIN.
The following should work:

```
tar cvf - /backupdir/ | ssh user@host "split -b 10G -d - backup.tar"
```

Hope that helps.